# python pyaudio bindings not executes sometimes

Tags: python, loops, speech-recognition, portaudio, pyaudio

I have downloaded and installed the pyaudio and portaudio.

For code 1,it works perfectly all the time without producing any errors.

The code 2, I have posted below works **sometimes successfully**.But **sometimes it shows up the error**  :

`>>> 
Please build and install the PortAudio Python bindings first.`

I just installed the pyaudio and portaudio directly.Should,I do something extra,so that all the time it running my code will be executiing successfully without the above error.
My microphones were properly installed,there is no problem over that,which I specially tested several times too.

Please help me to rectify my code 2 !

Code 1: http://pastebin.com/UvX0UNY9

Code 2:

```
import threading
import time
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyaudio
import _portaudio
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import Tkinter as tki
import tkFileDialog as th1
sr.Microphone()
class SpeechRecognizer(threading.Thread):
     def __init__(self):
         super(SpeechRecognizer, self).__init__()
         self.setDaemon(True)
         self.recognized_text = "initial"

     def run(self):
        r=sr.Recognizer()
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
          while True:
            audio = r.listen(source) 
            try:
                self.recognized_text=(r.recognize(audio))

            except LookupError:                            
                self.recognized_text=("Could not understand audio")
recognizer = SpeechRecognizer()
recognizer.start()
class App(object):
     def __init__(self,root):
         self.root = root
     # create a Frame for the Text and Scrollbar
         txt_frm = tki.Frame(self.root, width=900, height=900)
         txt_frm.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
         # ensure a consistent GUI size
         txt_frm.grid_propagate(False)
     # create first Text label, widget and scrollbar
         self.lbl1 = tki.Label(txt_frm, text="Type")
         self.lbl1.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=2,pady=2)
         self.recognized_text = StringVar()
         self.txt1 = tki.Text(txt_frm, borderwidth=3, relief="sunken", height=4,width=55)
         self.txt1.config(font=("consolas", 12), undo=True, wrap='word')
         self.txt1.grid(row=25, column=7, sticky="nsew", padx=2, pady=2)

         root.after(100, self.update_recognized_text)
         self.txt1.insert(0.0, recognizer.recognized_text)   
     def update_recognized_text(self):
         self.txt1.delete(0.0, END)
         self.txt1.insert(0.0, recognizer.recognized_text)
         root.after(100, self.update_recognized_text)
root = tki.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```